# How Put a space in between icon and category name?

Tags: magento2, category

Does anyone know how to put a space in between icon and the category name as circled below? This is not the smart menu on the home page, this is the category on left hand side on every other pages.

[image: magento_category_space]

Comment: use CSS property padding-let:10px

Comment: Do you know where its location is?

Answer (score 0):

You can also write custom css like (margin-left: 5px) for the same icon class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Replace '.category-link' and '.category-icon' with the actual class names you identified 

    .category-link {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

    .category-icon {
        margin-right: 10px;  Adjust this value as needed for the desired space 
     }
```